# Javascript/Node.js mapping an array with array of objects with minimum time complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects, recursive-datastructures

Suppose i have an array which has books id, For Example `[1,42,34,56,21,8,88,32]` all distinct, and i have an array of book objects example :

```
[
 {
  BookId: 34, BookName: Foo1
 },
 {
  BookId: 56, BookName: Bar1
 },
 {
  BookId: 1, BookName: Foo2
 },
.....
]
```

Books are not in same order as book ids array, although size of both arrays is equal, i want a resulting array of books, in-order with book id `array`.

I can use nested loops, but that would be m×n complexity.
So basically i wanna perform something like `SQL` join.

Is it possible to reduce the complexity?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to do it in `controllers` then you should specify which database are you using. IF `SQL` then there are several ways to perform `JOIN` while calling the API.

Comment: I have two databases, i get array of book ids from mongo, and then books from postgres, so its not possible to perform a join

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
const ids = [1,34,56,21];
const books = [
{BookId: 34, BookName: 'Foo34'},
{BookId: 56, BookName: 'Bar56'},
{BookId: 1, BookName: 'Foo1'},
{BookId: 21, BookName: 'Foo21'},
];

books.sort((a, b)=> ids.indexOf(a.BookId) - ids.indexOf(b.BookId));
console.log(books);
```

Comment: this works!!! idk why it was down voted, the other thread didn't work in my case as arrays were already sorted in that case